# Laravel 5.4 - Redirect back with message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to submit a form and redirect back to it after submitting. If the submit was successful, then I want to show a message, e.g. `successfully stored data`

I tried to redirect back with the message like this:

```
return redirect()->back()->with("message", "successfully stored data");
```

And in the view...

```
    @if(isset($message))
        <center><p> {{ $message }} </p></center>
    @endif
```

However, this does not work.

This is all I get back:

```
array:4 [▼
  "__env" => Factory {#89 ▶}
  "app" => Application {#3 ▶}
  "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#187 ▶}
  "AllSettings" => Settings {#202 ▶}
]
```

Comment: Does `->with(["message" => "..."]);` work? (Accessed with `\Session::get("message")`)

Comment: No does not work either.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Laravel 5.4 as I already mentioned in the title. And I just posted the relevant view snippet. No middleware used. I found the solution in the duplicate question.